# What was Maran Ovadia Yosef's reasoning for considering Ethiopian Jews halachically Jewish?

Tags: conversion-to-judaism, ethiopian-beta-israel

From my understanding the genetic makeup of Ethiopian Jews is mostly similar to those of the local Amhara and Tigrinya populations which suggests that the majority of their ancestors were converts as opposed to ethnic Jews. And there historically were practices among Ethiopian Jews that contradict halacha, such as the fact that they did not light candles on shabbos and did not wearing tefilin, which suggests that a geirus done in their community may not have been valid.

Why was Maran Ovadia so insistent that they were Jewish in spite of this?

Edit: Since someone asked, here is what Maran wrote on the subject: בהסתמך על הגאון הרדב”ז בתשובה (שאלות ותשובות דברי דוד הלכות אישות סימן ח) שאלו הפלשים בלי ספק משבט דן, ורק מפני שלא היו ביניהם חכמים מבעלי הקבלה תפסו להם פשטי המקראות, ודינם כתינוק הנשבה לבין הגוים, ודינם כישראל שאנו מצווים לפדותם ולהחיותם לכן באתי למסקנה שהפלשים הם צאצאי שבטי ישראל שהדרימו לכוש…והחלטתי כי הם יהודים שחייבים להצילם מטמיעה ומהתבוללות, ולהחיש עלייתם ארצה, ולחנכם ברוח תורתנו הקדושה, ולשתפם בבניין ארצנו הקדושה ושבו בנים לגבולם

Comment: This does not quite answer the question, but see: https://www.torahmusings.com/2017/12/rav-ovadya-yosef-whether-ethiopian-jews-need-reconvert/

Comment: Can you clarify what you feel needs to be explained in Rav Ovadia Yosef's Teshuva? He seems to be pretty clear and explicit that he felt they were descendants of Shevet Dan, plain and simple. And since "once a Jew, always a Jew", their lack of observance is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: The Ridbaz cited by Rav Yosef z”l was drawing from midrash found the collection from Jellinek called Beit Midrash. If I recall, those midrashim were genizah fragments from Alexandria in Egypt and preceded Rambam’s time.

Comment: He was relying on testimony from the Radvaz, who is an extremely important Halachic authority.

Comment: @Shmuel I think you have an answer there.

Comment: See also Gray Matter 1: The Halachic status of the Falash Mura: https://www.sefaria.org/Gray_Matter_I%2C_The_State_of_Israel%2C_The_Halachic_Status_of_the_Falash_Mura.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: @Shmuel Worth pointing out the author of that article points out Halakhic authorities who forbid marrying Karaites, but doesn't mention that again, Rabbis like Ovadia Yosef and others allow marrying of Karaites.

Answer (score 4):

> From my understanding the genetic makeup of Ethiopian Jews is mostly similar to those of the local...And there historically were practices among Ethiopian Jews that contradict halacha

R. Herzog argued along these lines, R. Yosef first cites his argument and responded as follows:

> אולם לא אכחד כי ראיתי להגאון רבי יצחק אייזיק הלוי הרצוג זצ"ל, במכתבו
> מיום כ"ט אדר א' תשי"ד, למחלקה לתרבות תורניתלגולה שע"י הסוכנות היהודית,
> שכתב לפקפק ביהדותם של הפלשים מפני שראה שהחוקרים מנוי וגמור עמם שהפלשים
> הם בני גזע לא יהודי שנתגיירו אי פעם, ואם כן הרי ברור שלא נתגיירו על
> מנת לשמור את היהדות שלנו על פי התורה שבעל פה, אלא יהדות שבדו מלבם,
> ודינם כמי שנתגייר עלמנת לשמור כל התורה חוץ מדקדוק אחד מדברי סופרים,
> שאין מקבלים אותו(בכורות ל ב),ואם כן שמא אינם יהודים במובן ההלכתי.וחזר
> על זה במכתבו מיום ג' שבט תשט"ו, כי שמא נתקבלו לגיור בבית דין של
> צדוקים, ואז יש לומר שאינם גרים, ולכן יש לגיירם בבית דין כשר, ואזתהיה
> להם תורת יהודים גמורים. עכת"ד. **ונוראות נפלאתי מה ראה על ככה לדחות
> דברי גאוני עולם שקובעים בודאות שאין ספק שהם משבט דן, מפני דבריהם של
> חוקרים שמטילים ספק ביהדותם, ומי נדחה מפני מי, אתמהה.** ומכל מקום היות
> שראיתי שעשה מעשה וציוה להרה"ג רבי נתן סאלם זצ"ל שיצרף עמו שני תלמידי
> חכמים, ויעשו הטפת דם ברית וטבילה, לשם גיור לחומרא, והקבוצות של הפלשים
> שעלו ארצה היו מתי מעט של כמה עשרות בכל פעם, ולא הביעו שום התנגדות
> להטפת דם ברית וטבילה, לא רציתי לחלוק למעשה על הגריא"ה הרצוג
> הנ"ל,ואמרתי מהיות טוב אל תקרי רע .אולם לדינאלא כן אנכי עמדי, ודעתי שיש
> לסמוך על הפוסקים הנ"ל, שהפלשים יהודים לכל דבר, ואינם צריכים גיור אפילו
> לחומרא

In short, genetic/socio-historical research is irrelevant where a late medieval rabbi of great stature (the Radbaz) had unequivocally and decisively deemed them to be the descendants of the Tribe of Dan.

You may not find his reasoning persuasive (certainly R. Herzog, R. Feinstein, R. Waldenberg, et al did not), but that is the core pillar of his argument in favor of accepting them as Jews despite such external evidence.

Comment: I will just add that we have historical accounts of the Ethiopian Jews appearing on the scene as practicing Jews [with laws between karaites and rabbinates] and then disappearing again throughout the centuries. This also distinguishes them from their Christian neighbors.